# .htaccess redirect with mod_rewrite

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved my wiki from

```
http://jklatex.square7.de/wiki/doku.php/start
```

to

```
http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/start
```

and now i want to redirect the URL with mod_rewrite. My .htaccess is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/wiki/doku.php/(.*)$ http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't understand why it does not work :-(

Any hints?

Comment: Are you definitely using an Apache server? If not, .htaccess may not even be in use. If you rename .htaccess, does your site break?

Comment: Yes, the server is Apache/2.4 and according to the forum mod_rewrite is active.

Comment: After renaming to `.htaccess2` nothing special happens. Why should this break the page?

Comment: Got it! The problem is the leading slash. `RewriteRule ^wiki/doku.php/(.*)$ http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/$1 [R,NC,L]` works.

Comment: Nice one. Please answer your own question with the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading slash is evil! ;-) The slash is part of `RewriteBase`.

Changing the `RewriteRule` to

```
RewriteRule ^wiki/doku.php/(.*)$ http://logicpuzzle.square7.de/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

works as desired.

Comment: "The slash is part of RewriteBase" - Just to clarify, the _leading slash_ on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ has nothing to do with `RewriteBase`. In per-directory .htaccess files, the `RewriteRule` pattern matches against the filesystem/URL path after having removed the directory-prefix. The directory-prefix is the filesystem path of the .htaccess file and always _ends with a slash_, so the URL-path that matches never starts with a slash.